# Inserting Radio Button selected value into Text Area in another JFrame

Tags: java

I'm a newbie in programming and I just recently started using GUI builder and I'm having a problem inputting the value from a radio button into a text area in another Jframe. The values don't show up.

ospta1 is the text area in the other JFrame. rb2 the radio button. Under the ActionPerformed event I put this:

```
OSPrint osp= new OSPrint();
osp.ospta1.setText(this.rb2.getText());
```

I set the Text Area's accessibility to public static and I used a similar syntax in a button to input the value from a text field into a text area, and it works fine.

```
OSPrint osp=new OSPrint();
osp.ospta2.setText(this.ostf1.getText());
osp.setVisible(true);
this.setVisible(false);
```

Is there something I'm not doing right? Can you suggest any alternatives?

Comment: Take a look at the Model View Controller architecture.  Ideally, the radio button should be updating a backing model when selected.  While the text area is listening for updates to the model.

Comment: I found a workaround to it, but thanks for the advice :)